# What is the most efficient way to do SIMD unsigned 64 bit comparison (CMHS) on ARMv7 with NEON?

Tags: assembly, simd, webassembly, neon, armv7

Specifically, we're looking to know what would be a good ARMv7+NEON implementation for unsigned 64-bit comparison for possible inclusion into the WebAssembly SIMD standard. Unlike ARM64 which has [CMHS](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0596/h/simd-and-floating-point-instructions-alphabetic-order/cmhs-register-compare-unsigned-higher-or-same-vector), this doesn't have a native instruction on ARMv7.  However, we received a remarkable result for the sister question to this:

[What is the most efficient way to support CMGT with 64bit signed comparisons on ARMv7a with Neon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191073/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-support-cmgt-with-64bit-signed-comparisons-on/65191074#65191074)

Comment: How do you want to get the result of the comparison - a boolean (0/1, or 0/-1?) in a SIMD register, or in an integer register, or setting the NZCV flags, or a conditional branch, or ???

Comment: @NateEldredge: Based on previous questions from the OP, they're considering a SIMD primitive operation as part of WebAssembly, so I assume they're thinking about a SIMD result.  That would normally be 0 / -1 like comparison primitives that do have hardware support.  Although on x86 it's only available in HW from AVX512 which produces a mask register result (bitmap, not vector).  Designs for new SIMD abstraction layers might want to consider ways to work efficiently with mask-reg or vector compare results if they care about exposing AVX-512 stuff (like unsigned integer compare).

Comment: At worst, unsigned greater-than-or-equal-to is `vqsubq_u64(b, a) == 0` and
unsigned greater-than is `(vqsubq_s64(b, a) ^ (a ^ b)) < 0`.

Comment: Remember that we don't have cmgt on ARMv7+neon.  We're proposing your variant.

Comment: Remember `x < 0` is `vshrq_n_s64(x, 63)`

Comment: Okay, can you post that unsigned greater than solution as an answer?